# left and top properties are not animated

Tags: html, css, css-animations

In the animation below the transform is animated correctly, but the left and top properties are not. Why is this?

```css
.element-animation {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  animation: animationFrames ease 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes animationFrames {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    left: 0px;
    top: -90px;
  }
  75% {
    left: 200px;
    top: -90px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(2) scaleY(2) skewX(45deg) skewY(45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element-animation"></div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KxM68/6/

Comment: don't work is NOT a valid problem description.

Comment: But I have code and animation DONT WORK, so what is the valid description?

Comment: Nor is it valid grammar.

Comment: @KubaŻukowski you should describe expected result, and actual result.

Comment: I had the same problem and I decided to use transform (translateY) instead. It sounds to me like we cant animate transform and top at the same time...

Answer (score 2):

Your animation relies on positioning, therefore you have to add a `position` property:

```
.element-animation{
    position:relative;
}
```

```css
.element-animation {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  animation: animationFrames ease 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  position: relative;
}
@keyframes animationFrames {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    left: 0px;
    top: -90px;
  }
  75% {
    left: 200px;
    top: -90px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element-animation"></div>
```

For older browsers you may need to add the `-webkit-` prefix for the animation property. Check browser compatibility [over on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

Answer (score 0):

You should copy all the code for every Browser. not just standard.

so it should contain the following stuff

```
-webkit-animation: animationFrames linear 0.7s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-transform-origin: ;
```

see in http://jsfiddle.net/KxM68/8/